# How do I verify that a CRL is in the security MarkLogic database?

Tags: marklogic

The documentation states that the CRL is inserted into the security database, but I'm unable to find the file with xdmp:document-get("pca3.crl") against the security database.

https://docs.marklogic.com/pki:insert-certificate-revocation-list

```
  xquery version "1.0-ml"; 

  import module namespace pki = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/pki" 
  at "/MarkLogic/pki.xqy";

  let $URI := "http://crl.verisign.com/pca3.crl"

  return
    pki:insert-certificate-revocation-list(
       $URI, 
       xdmp:document-get($URI)/binary() )

  (: Inserts a CRL from Verisign into the database. :)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list all of the certifiate-revocation-lists with the following  command in query console:

```
cts:uri-match("*crls*")
```

The URL is made up of the following parts:
(maybe some root) + /crls/ + (hash64 integer of the original URI).
Therefore, your assumption of the original filename or URL being a visible part of the URL is invalid.

If you want to verify your CRLS, then this should work as a quick way:

```
declare namespace pki = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/pki"

doc()[.//pki:url="http://crl.verisign.com/pca3.crl"]
```

Furthermore, if you want to find the document, it can be found like this:

```
declare namespace pki = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/pki"

fn:document-uri(doc()[.//pki:url="http://crl.verisign.com/pca3.crl"])
```

Note that I avoided using element value or word searches because these are likely not enabled for the security database.